# Picklist value with "Like"

Tags: picklist, formula-field

I have to select a value from a pick list having values starting with 'PR'

I have tried

```
ISPICKVAL(Order_Type__c, 'PR%')
```

But I am not able to use expression Like or wildcards here.

Answer (score 8):

Use the Left formula along with the text formula and compare that to PR.

```
LEFT(TEXT(Order_Type__c),2) = "PR"
```

Answer (score 2):

CONTAINS(TEXT(Exchanged_Through__c), 'QC')

Comment: i realize you answered your own question but the answer doesn't correspond to the question (starts with versus contains) - for others, you might want to align question with answer